# How to change login route name

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5.6

I have created a laravel project. My login URL is like that:

```
http://localhost/project_name/public/login
```

I want to change the route name `login` to `user` and `registration` route to `new-user`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the routes yourself inside your routes/web.php file:

```
Route::get('user', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::get('new-user', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
```

These will be created next to your original login routes if you use `Auth::routes();` inside your routes/web.php.

If you want to remove the `Auth::routes();` you can offcourse, but you will have to add the post methods as well from the original login routes. You can check where they are going by doing `php artisan route:list` in your terminal to figure out how to point these and to which method.